# How to fine tune SQL Server query execution plan generation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan, sql-server-performance

I have a large "Deals" table (1.3 million rows) that needs to be displayed on a paginated grid in my application, the application also includes filters to help the user search through those rows, the generated SQL follows the structure below:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DealID] DESC) AS RowNumber, * 
  FROM (
    select d.DealID, a.[Description] as Asset, 
    from Deals d
    inner join Assets a on d.AssetID = a.AssetID
  ) as Sorted
  where Asset like '%*my asset%' 
) as Sorted
```

My problem is with the execution plan generated for this query, because it's ordered by DealID, SQL Server is choosing the clustered index on DealID to execute this query and performs a clustered Index Scan on this table that has 1.3 million rows, but the query is also being filtered by Asset and there are only 171 rows that satisfy the filter, so it's much faster to use the non-clustered index on the asset first and then sort the resulting rows, I'm already able to fix this issue by adding the `WITH INDEX(IX_Asset_ID))` hint into the query, but the problem is that since this is a generated query, this will add a lot of complexity to the code the generates this query.

So my question is, is there a way to get SQL Server to detect this situation without the hint? Maybe update statistics or something like that? Or even moving the hint to the end of the query would actually help since the middle of the query is actually a report written by the client.

--Edit--

As pointed out in the comments there are a few issues with the query, but those were actually created by the fact that I attempted to create a minimal reproducible example of the problem so I omitted the paging part of the query, structure below is a more complete version that should make more sense:

```
SELECT TOP @pageLength * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DealID] DESC) AS RowNumber, * 
    FROM (
        SELECT d.DealID, a.[Description] AS Asset, FROM Deals d
        INNER JOIN Assets a on d.AssetID = a.AssetID
    ) AS Sorted
    WHERE Asset LIKE '%*my asset%'
) AS Paged 
WHERE RowNumber > @startRow
ORDER BY RowNumber
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Your `TOP 10` is currently not guaranteed. Chances are that it will be in the same order as required for the `ROW_NUMBER` but without an `ORDER BY` on the query itself there is no guarantee of this

Comment: Updating stats is the first step since that provides more accurate row count estimates the optimizer needs to generate efficient plans. The `LIKE` with the leading wildcard makes good estimates a challenge, especially if your actual query is parameterized. An `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint may help.

Comment: What plan do you get with `OPTION (USE HINT ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'))`? This may be enough to give your desired plan anyway. It will be costing on the basis that it won't have to read *that* many rows from the scan before finding 10 that match the join condition

Comment: +1 to what Martin Smith is saying - what you are doing is not guaranteeing that the top 10 you select will be in sorted order.  There is no reason for you to even use sequence functions (row_number) in this query at all. you should be doing select * from (select top 10 ... from d join a on ... where ... order by dealid desc).  Doing a generic wildcard search isn't giving the optimizer much help since its stats don't cover this, so what you can do is use a plan guide or query store to add hints to the query without changing the sql generation layer.

Comment: @MartinSmith the `OPTION (USE HINT ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'))` gives me the correct plan, which does a scan on the Assets table (very small table) and a Seek on the Deals table using the index on the AssetID column.

This looks correct to me, I'm just reading more into `DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL` now to make sure I understand what the assumption is.

Comment: `WHERE Asset LIKE '%*my asset%'` -- This is killing performance. The engine needs to check the entire million rows each time you  run the query. Use [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16) for this.

Comment: @TheImpaler - `Asset` is `Assets.Description` - we have no information about the size of `Assets`. Only that 171 rows match the condition. In any event it sounds as though acceptable performance is achieved without FTS dependent on plan selection

Comment: @EduardoWada - Do you see the perf issue just on later pages or on page 1 too?

Comment: @MartinSmith The issue happens on page 1, to be honest, I think I understand why it happens at this point and `'DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'` is indeed the solution, the problem is that the table is large and then it takes very long to find the 10th row that meets the criteria since there is only 171 of them in a million, when we disable it, it just makes a better plan for this situation, also, I think the asset I'm testing is a recent asset, which means the rows are at the end of the table and not evenly distributed.

Comment: yeah there is quite a lot that can go wrong with the scan plan. In the first instance it may well not estimate the number of rows that will be returned from the join correctly anyway. Especially with the wildcard predicate. And then even if it does manage to get that estimate spot on they still may not be evenly distributed through the index so it can still end up reading a lot more rows than the row goal adjusted estimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution for me was to use the DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL hint.

I think what's happening here is that SQL Server is being too optimistic about the query only requiring 10 rows and is scanning too much of the table because if thinks it won't take long to find the first 10 but in reality it's better to use the available indexes, adding the hint causes it to change the plan and the query runs quickly.

```
SELECT TOP @pageLength * FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DealID] DESC) AS RowNumber, * 
    FROM (
        SELECT d.DealID, a.[Description] AS Asset, FROM Deals d
        INNER JOIN Assets a on d.AssetID = a.AssetID
    ) AS Sorted
    WHERE Asset LIKE '%*my asset%'
) AS Paged 
WHERE RowNumber > @startRow
ORDER BY RowNumber
OPTION(RECOMPILE, USE HINT ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to page based off your clustered index key values, something like this

```
SELECT TOP (@pageLength)  
d.DealID, 
a.[Description] AS Asset, 
@startRowNumber + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DealID] DESC) AS RowNumber 
FROM Deals d
INNER JOIN Assets a on d.AssetID = a.AssetID
WHERE DealId > @startDealId
 and a.[Description] LIKE '%*my asset%'
ORDER BY DealId
```

This technique is sometimes called "keyset pagination", and it leverages the ordered index to allow SQL to seek directly to the next clustered index key after the last page.  You track the rows based on the key value rather than the generated row number.

Comment: This is a nice optimization but the "DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL" gave good enough results for me and in practice, the `ORDER BY` part of my query is dynamic and accepts multiple sorting levels so tracking the sorting key is a bigger change to the application.